# Open app and pass parameters with deep linking using Electron (macOS)

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, custom-protocol, custom-url-protocol

I want to open app and pass parameters with deep linking using Electron (macOS).

[Project 'electron-deep-linking-mac-win' is on GitHub](https://github.com/oikonomopo/electron-deep-linking-mac-win).

### [image]

Edited `package.json`, following [‘electron-builder’ quick-setup-guide](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder#quick-setup-guide) to produce mac installer:

```
{
  "name": "electron-deep-linking-osx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application with Deep Linking (OSX)",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/oikonomopo/electron-deep-linking-osx",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "osx",
    "deep-linking"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "1.6.6",
    "electron-builder": "17.1.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "your.id",
    "mac": {
      "category": "your.app.category.type"
    },
    "protocols": {
      "name": "myApp",
      "schemes": ["myApp"]
    }
  }
}
```

---

Edited `main.js`, appended code to [register `myapp` url scheme protocol](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appsetasdefaultprotocolclientprotocol-path-args-macos-windows), listen ['open-url' events](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#event-open-url-macos) and log the arguments:

```
const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
// Module with utilities for working with file and directory paths.
const path = require('path')
// Module with utilities for URL resolution and parsing.
const url = require('url')
// Module to display native system dialogs for opening and saving files, alerting, etc.
const dialog = electron.dialog

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.

// The setAsDefaultProtocolClient only works on packaged versions of the application
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('myApp')

// Protocol handler for osx
app.on('open-url', function (event, url) {
  event.preventDefault();
  log("open-url event: " + url)

  dialog.showErrorBox('open-url', `You arrived from: ${url}`)
})

// Log both at terminal and at browser
function log(s) {
    console.log(s)
    if (mainWindow && mainWindow.webContents) {
        mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`console.log("${s}")`)
    }
}
```

---

Steps to come to life:-)

```
# Clone this repository
git clone https://github.com/oikonomopo/electron-deep-linking-mac-win.git
# Go into the repository
cd electron-deep-linking-mac-win
# Install dependencies
npm install
# Run the app
npm start
# Produce installer
npm run dist
```

After running the installer (`electron-deep-linking-mac-win/dist/electron-quick-start-1.0.0.dmg`), i try to open electron-deep-linking-os app with deep linking, entering `myapp://param` at Safari address bar.

1. If app is opened, it activates and i can see the dialog and the log `open-url event: myapp://param`!
2. **If app is closed, it opens, dialog is shown with proper url but isn't logged to dev console!**

**Why with `dialog` module `url` is showing properly, but isn't logged to dev console?
 How to log it?**

*Looking for solution using only [`electron-builder`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/) ([which uses `electron-packager`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113815/electron-builder-vs-electron-packager))!*

Comment: At Windows i have accomplished the same feature!
I would like the simpler solution, ideally using just the 'electron-builder'.

Comment: Possible indications: 1.https://discuss.atom.io/t/custom-protocol-and-closed-app/37030 2.https://github.com/masahirompp/electron-open-url-sample 3.https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3847

Comment: Isn't updating Info.plist is requited for Mac apps? Where are you updating Info.plist?

Comment: One possible issue here is that you have initialized `mainWindow` to `undefined` because of your initial declaration 
`let mainWindow` but you go on to compare it to `null`

I'd suggest you set it to `null` from the onset or compare it to `undefined` everywhere you need to.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Solved for both macOS and win32 ( Updated project ['electron-deep-linking-mac-win' on GitHub](https://github.com/oikonomopo/electron-deep-linking-mac-win)).

---

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "electron-deeplinking-macos-win32",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Minimal Electron application with deep inking (macOS/win32)",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/oikonomopo/electron-deep-linking-osx",
  "author": "oikonomopo",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "1.6.6",
    "electron-builder": "17.1.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "oikonomopo.electron-deeplinking-macos-win32",
    "protocols": {
      "name": "electron-deep-linking",
      "schemes": ["myapp"]
    },
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.Reference"
    },
    "win": {
    }
  }
}
```

---

`main.js`:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
// Module with utilities for working with file and directory paths.
const path = require('path')
// Module with utilities for URL resolution and parsing.
const url = require('url')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

// Deep linked url
let deeplinkingUrl

// Force Single Instance Application
const shouldQuit = app.makeSingleInstance((argv, workingDirectory) => {
  // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.

  // Protocol handler for win32
  // argv: An array of the second instance’s (command line / deep linked) arguments
  if (process.platform == 'win32') {
    // Keep only command line / deep linked arguments
    deeplinkingUrl = argv.slice(1)
  }
  logEverywhere("app.makeSingleInstance# " + deeplinkingUrl)

  if (win) {
    if (win.isMinimized()) win.restore()
        win.focus()
  }
})
if (shouldQuit) {
    app.quit()
    return
}

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Protocol handler for win32
  if (process.platform == 'win32') {
    // Keep only command line / deep linked arguments
    deeplinkingUrl = process.argv.slice(1)
  }
  logEverywhere("createWindow# " + deeplinkingUrl)

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// Define custom protocol handler. 
// Deep linking works on packaged versions of the application!
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('myapp')

// Protocol handler for osx
app.on('open-url', function (event, url) {
  event.preventDefault()
  deeplinkingUrl = url
  logEverywhere("open-url# " + deeplinkingUrl)
})

// Log both at dev console and at running node console instance
function logEverywhere(s) {
    console.log(s)
    if (mainWindow && mainWindow.webContents) {
        mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`console.log("${s}")`)
    }
}
```

`main.js` code description:

- At `let deeplinkingUrl` we keep the provided url.
- [On macOS you need to listen to the app.open-url event, while on Windows the url should be available in process.argv (in the main process).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39292648/electron-js-deep-linking-example-of-how-to-use-deep-linking?rq=1)

  - On macOS platform this is captured at [`'open-url'` event](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#event-open-url-macos), we set it with `deeplinkingUrl = url`! (See `// Protocol handler for osx`)
  - On win32 platform this is saved at [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv) together with other arguments. To get only the provided url, `deeplinkingUrl = argv.slice(1)`.  (See `// Protocol handler for win32`)
  - At [`app.makeSingleInstance` method](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appmakesingleinstancecallback) we check in which platform we are and we set `deeplinkingUrl` accordingly! If we are on win32 platform, the url is located at `argv` variable from callback, else on macOS should have already been set at `'open-url'` event! (See `// Force Single Instance Application`)

Comment: This works well with Mac but it doesn't work with Linux. Do I have to do any specific setting for Linux? is there any way I can check if the app is opened with deep-link or something get fired if I click on the button with deeplink URL? 
something like `open-url` for linux?

Comment: makeSingleInstance is now depreciated

Answer (score 5):

You should be setting up the `open-url` event in the `will-finish-launching` callback [as per the docs](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#event-will-finish-launching). I had similar weird behaviour with `open-file` until it was setup within the `will-finish-launching` callback.

You notice they've done it this way in [the example you link to](https://github.com/masahirompp/electron-open-url-sample/blob/9e5b181cbcfeee32f83f0965b2433fd7a6bfae01/appsrc/main/main.ts#L20).

Although it mentions this under `will-finish-launching`, it should really mention this under the `open-url` and `open-file` docs too as its quite easy to miss.

```
app.on('will-finish-launching', () => {
  // Protocol handler for osx
  app.on('open-url', (event, url) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    log("open-url event: " + url)
  })
});
```

Comment: Tried but doesn't solve the issue. It is again capturing url, only when app is already opened!

Comment: Update: I've updated code etc. Now i can see the Dialog with the url. but can't log it at first isntance. After that i can both see the dialog with the url and the log at dev console! Any idea?

Comment: Also with current code, seems there is no need to mention 'open-url' under 'will-finish-launching'!