# 'Second-instance' fires instead of 'open-url' in electron on mac

Tags: macos, electron

We have an electron app that we're setting up to launch from protocol links following the structure described here: https://github.com/oikonomopo/electron-deep-linking-mac-win (found from [Open app and pass parameters with deep linking using Electron (macOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912119/open-app-and-pass-parameters-with-deep-linking-using-electron-macos))

Once the app is installed, we either open the app from finder/launchpad or can invoke the app from a browser using `myapp://someparams`.

If I invoke `myapp://someparams` when the app is closed, the app opens and the main process fires the `open-url` event for mac as expected and I can grab the parameters from the url. If the app was initially opened via this method, re-invoking the `myapp://someparams` continues to focus the app and fire `open-url` as expected.

However, if the app was initially opened from the finder, launchpad, or command line, invoking `myapp://someparams` causes the `second-instance` event to fire instead and I haven't been able to find a way to get the url that was used to invoke the app. Windows works as expected since the second parameter to the `second-instance` event contains the protocol as a parameter but that isn't the case with mac.

So the question is - is there a way to grab the protocol/url from the `second-instance` event on mac? Or is there another way around this?

I did see this snippet from the docs: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#apprequestsingleinstancelock

```
On macOS, the system enforces single instance automatically when users try to open a second instance of your app in Finder, and the open-file and open-url events will be emitted for that. However when users start your app in command line, the system's single instance mechanism will be bypassed, and you have to use this method to ensure single instance.
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm running into the exact same problem

Comment: I was not. I ended up putting in an issue (https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20088) in the electron Repo but I never heard back.

Answer (score -1):

- You should set LSMultipleInstancesProhibited to true in info.plist.
- If you are using electron builder, you can set 'LSMultipleInstancesProhibited: true' at mac.extendInfo
  For example

```
mac: {
  ...
  extendInfo: {
    LSMultipleInstancesProhibited: true,
  }
}
```

Comment: where does this go? In `package.json`?