# Electron+React deep link

Tags: reactjs, electron, deep-linking

I work on Electron + React application(with react-router of course), and should implement deep linking there. I almost handled this task, but I can't get parameters from a deep link in React. I already read this article [Open app and pass parameters with deep linking using Electron (macOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912119/open-app-and-pass-parameters-with-deep-linking-using-electron-macos), and I getting params in electron file. But I don't know how can get this link data in react code. I would appreciate it if someone could help with this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send data from the main process to a renderer process (the window that is rendering your React code), you need to use [`contents.send(channel, ...args)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args).

For your case, the communication would look something like this for macOS

```js
// Protocol handler for macOS
app.on('open-url', (event, url) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  // send url data to React process
  reactBrowserWindow.webContents.send('testChannel', url)
})
```

and inside the React code (Node integration needs to be enabled or this code should be in a preload script)

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron")

ipcRenderer.on('testChannel', (event, url) => {
  console.log(url)
})
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! You made my day!