# Electron: How do I remove unwanted modules?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I am in the process of developing my first Electron application, and I have a few questions regarding deployment.

I am developing on MacOS and using electron-packager to package it for both MacOS and Windows.

There appear to be a large number of modules in the node_modules directory. I know they don’t take up so much space, but the number of files certainly slows down the packaging and zipping/unzipping process. How can I trim the unused modules?

There also appear to be a large number of locales which I don’t use. Ditto.

Comment: I don’t suppose there’s any point in asking why this question was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you install modules as `devDependencies`, they will all be pruned automatically before packaging.

If you're using electron-packager you can use the [ignore](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#ignore) option and regular expression to exclude files.

I suggest you to use electron-builder instead of electron-packager. You can get the best difference of both here [difference between electron-builder and electron-packager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113815/electron-builder-vs-electron-packager).

If you're using electron-builder you can define patterns as `files` in the config. In this case `!**/node_modules/*` will exclude all of node_modules.